# Rails 3 - .each works, .find_each fails -> ActiveRecord::JDBCError: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying >= integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've got a lot (+100,000) of records I'm trying to process through a query.

I was using something like:

```
BigRecordPull.where(name: ['x','y','z']).each { |record| do_some_action record }
```

Because this isn't good from a memory management perspective, I wanted to instead use find_each as outlined [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) so now the code looks like this:

```
BigRecordPull.where(name: ['x','y','z']).find_each { |record| do_some_action record }
```

The issue is when I go to fire the code I get the following error:

> ActiveRecord::JDBCError: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying >= integer
>     Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

If I review the SQL query created in the logs I get back something like:

```
SELECT  "big_record_pull".* FROM "big_record_pull" WHERE "big_record_pull"."name" IN ('x','y','z') AND ("big_record_pull"."name" >= 0)
```

ActiveRecord seems to add the part, 'AND ("big_record_pull"."name" >= 0)' and that seems to be what's causing the problem. Name in this example is a varchar. The extra wrinkle is I don't control the postgresql db my rails project plugs into so I can't just re-run a migration to try and fix this issue. I'm hoping there's some sort of work around.... I'd like to avoid running raw SQL.

**Extra info**
In the example above, big_record_pull.name is also a foreign_key

Comment: Is name the primary key for the table?

Comment: name would be a foreign_key for another table... It may seem a little confusing. let's say big_record_pull was a table with 3 attributes, id would be the primary key, name would be a foreign key (varchar), and description would be a varchar (for giggles). whether you search for name or description, the sql query is similar in that it creates that extra big_record_pull.name >= 0 part I don't want/need

Comment: Weird. I would only expect/understand the above if the primary key was set (in the rails model) to name instead of the default of id

Comment: @FrederickCheung, you were right, after reviewing my models, name is being used as part of a primary key for this particular table, and as a foreign key to another table.... As you may have guessed I've tried to use a simple example for a much more complicated table... Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was related to a gem: composite_primary_keys-5.0.14.gem.

Solution was found, [here](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys/issues/148)

> See lib/composite_primary_keys/relation/batches.rb:28:in `find_in_batches'
>   Change this block to:

```
  self.primary_key.each do |key|
      condition = case relation.columns_hash[key.to_s].type
        when :string
          table[key].not_eq ''
        when :integer
          table[key].gteq start
      end
      relation = relation.where(condition)
    end
```